# Java Comparator for Objects with multiple fields

Tags: java, sorting, object, comparator

I have an Object `Collection` with 5 fields:

```
id;
entityType;
entityId;
brandId;
productId;
```

To sort an `ArrayList` of `Collection` I have written the following `Comparaor`.

```
Comparator<Collection> collectionComparator = new Comparator<Collection>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Collection collection1, Collection collection2) {
        if(collection1.getId().equals(collection2.getId())) {
            if(collection1.getEntityType().equals(collection2.getEntityType())) {
                if(collection1.getEntityId().equals(collection2.getEntityId())) {
                    if(collection1.getBrandId().equals(collection2.getBrandId())) {
                        return collection1.getProductId().compareTo(collection2.getProductId());
                    } else {
                        return collection1.getBrandId().compareTo(collection2.getBrandId());
                    }
                } else {
                    return collection1.getEntityId().compareTo(collection2.getEntityId());
                }
            } else {
                return collection1.getEntityType().compareTo(collection2.getEntityType());
            }
        } 

        return collection1.getId().compareTo(collection2.getId());
    }
};
```

Is this the right way to implement `Comparator` on the object which has multiple fields to compare?

Comment: "Right"? What are you asking? Why not just test your code?

Comment: its wrong as there is no getId on Collection, unless you've implemented it yourself, which is probably unnecessary too

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user is asking us to write test cases that user is too lazy to write himself.

Comment: @djechlin sorry, I asked in a wrong way.

Comment: It is not a Java Collection but a Collection as in fashion?

Comment: @djechlin I am sorry, but I must say, your answer is not helping me. I asked the question in a wrong manner. I have edited it. And before saying "user is asking us to write test cases that user is too lazy to write himself." you should go through that user's profile to see if he is lazy or not.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic the `Collection` term is related to my project .

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for codereview?

Comment: What do you mean "right way"? Is this a code review? Did you not read the javadoc for Comparator? Are you not sure whether this works in, e.g., a sort, and didn't bother to try it? My comments still stand and looking at your profile only tells me you should already know this is a very substandard question.

Comment: This question would be better asked on codereview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method might be correct, but it is inefficient (unnecessarily calls equals) and difficult to read. It could be rewritten something like this:

```
public int compare(Collection c1, Collection c2)
{
    int n;
    n = c1.id.compareTo(c2.id);
    if (n != 0) return n;
    n = c1.entityType.compareTo(c2.entityType);
    if (n != 0) return n;
    n = c1.brandId.compareTo(c2.brandId);
    if (n != 0) return n;
    return c1.productId.compareTo(c2.productId);
}
```

Even better is to use a library method which abstracts all this logic away so you don't have to think about it. E.g. using [apache.commons.lang CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html)

```
public int compare(Collection c1, Collection c2)
{
    return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(c1.id, c2.id)
            .append(c1.entityType, c2.entityType)
            .append(c1.brandId, c2.brandId)
            .append(c1.productId, c2.productId)
            .toComparison();
}
```

Comment: Also, if you need a reverse sort on a particular field compare the field in c2 to c1 and append, `.append(c2.brandId, c1.brandId)`

Answer (score 0):

First, `Collection` is a class from `java.util` package, so it's probably not the best idea to name your own class `Collection` too, although it is certainly possible.

Second, JDK8 have some neat ways to create comparators, check here: [jdk8 comparators](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-sort-lambda)

Esspecially section 6 and 9.

**EDIT: Without JKD8:**

When comparing by 5 different attributes, I wouldn't hardcode the comparasion like that, you can always create your own comparator chainer (something like point 9 from previous link) and chain 5 separate comparators together.

Comment: I am not using Jdk8 and the `Collection` is related to my project.